# any free to download vulnerable SQL injection script?

Tags: sql, code-injection

in a week, I will have to present in the university about SQL injection and how is this hack implemented. I was wondering if there is any available vulnerable scripts that i can download and put in a local server to test on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At least 50% of the PHP SQL questions here on Stackoverflow would qualify ;-p

Comment: Serious answer: Have a look at Damn Vulnerable Web Application http://www.dvwa.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

Simple Example Here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Here's some PHP Code and a query that shows why not using parameters is dangerous:

```
txtUserId = getRequestString("UserId");
txtSQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = " + txtUserId;
```

Normally, if a user enters an ID as a number (e.g. 2), the query will look like this:
    txtSQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = 2";

However, if the user enters a value of "0 OR 1=1", they might be able to select regardless of whether the selected ID exists.  The 1=1 part will ensure all records will be returned.

```
txtSQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = 0 or 1=1";
```

Even more dangerous is this example where a user id is sent as "0; DROP Table Users".  In the right environment, something like this might drop the table, doing damage.  It produces this query:

```
 txtSQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = 0; DROP Table Users";
```